# fgets() doesn't seem to move the file pointer correctly

Tags: c++, fgets, fseek, ftell

I have an application that reads from a text file that is being simultaneously written to by another application. The application that reads the file opens it in text mode using C - fopen. The lines in the file can be big, like up to a few 100 megs in size. For this reason we have a function that reads chunks of 4K from the file using fgets and appends it in a string object until it manages to read a complete line. It is possible that the application which is writing into the file has written a partial line when a read attempt was made. Out custom ReadLine function handles this scenario by detecting end-of-file, re-setting the file pointer to last known good position, and discarding the text that's been read already.

Here's how that function looks like:

```
#define MAX_BUF_SIZE 4096

bool ReadLine(FILE* fp, std::string& result, bool& isEof) {

    result.clear();
    long const lastOffset = ftell(fp);
    bool hasReadOneLine = false;
    isEof = false;

    debug_print(lastOffset);

    while (!hasReadOneLine && !isEof) {

        char dataRead[MAX_BUF_SIZE];
        memset(dataRead, 0, sizeof(dataRead));

        if (fgets(dataRead, MAX_BUF_SIZE, fp) == NULL) {

            if (feof(fp)) {
                debug_print("Flag 1");
                isEof = true;
            } else {
                debug_print("Flag 2");
                result.clear();
                fseek(fp, lastOffset, SEEK_SET); //reset the file pointer to where it was
                return false;
            }

        }

        result += dataRead;
        hasReadOneLine = (result[result.length()-1] == '\n');

    } // end loop

    if (!hasReadOneLine) {
        debug_print("Flag 3");
        result.clear();
        fseek(fp, lastOffset, SEEK_SET); //reset the file pointer to where it was
        return false;
    }

    // drop the new-line character ...
    if (result[ result.length()-1] == '\n') {
        result.resize(result.size() - 1);
    }

    return true;

}
```

Problem: 
I have run into a scenario where after reading a full line from the file, the ReadLine() function is returning the last chunk from the previously read line when it is called again to read the next line. I logged the value of lastOffset returned by the ftell() and noticed that in that rare scenario the fgets has not moved the file pointer to the end of the line which it read.

I added some debug lines but in my case only thing that got printed was the lastOffset value.

In the call where the ReadLine returned an incomplete line, the value of lastOffset is: 21563617
Length of the incomplete line is: 920

In the call before where it returned a complete line, the value of lastOffset is: 21442207
Length of the line read in this previous call is: 122331 (including new-line)

My question is: has anyone ever encountered similar problem? What is your opinion about what could be potentially going wrong? I am not necessarily looking for a complete answer but just some pointers about what could potentially go wrong.

** UPDATE **

I managed to reproduce the problem with a small utility, writing in a file in chunks of 4K and with a sleep interval of 10 ms, while the other program (that uses the function above) reading from the same file simultaneously.

Looks like doing fseek() to re-set the file-pointer is a bad option in the function above as re-setting the file-pointer to a previous position does not necessarily clear the C-library's own internal buffer. I am still not fully convinced with this explanation as in some cases (repro cases) the file pointer resetting never happened.

Anyway, I did some more search on the web, and some thread seemed to suggest using lower-level streams and handle the buffering in the library itself. So I have changed the implementation of the function above and its other helpers to do just that. I am now using _sopen_s()/_read()/_lseek() for Windows and standard POSIX interface for Linux/Solaris to perform the lower-level IO handling. With these changes it seems to work, I am not seeing the issue anymore.

Thank you all for your time. All your input is much appreciated.

Suman

** UPDATE 2 **

Well now I definitely know the reason. The problem is that ftell() and fseek() are unreliable if the file is opened in text mode. If the file is opened in binary mode, then the function above works fine.

Here's a link to an article where someone else found this issue before: http://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?f=20&t=420490

This is a good thing, because now I have a fix that requires changing 1 line, instead of 200! :-)

Comment: Before anything else, make sure you are studying the right language. You seem to be confused about its name.

Comment: Could `result.length()-1` ever result in -1?  Do not you want a `break` after `isEof = true;`?

Comment: Good point. However, I think that should never happen because of the variable "hasReadOneLine". If the value of this variable is "false" after the loop, then the function will return false. If it is true, then it will at least have one character assuming the application that writes to the file has written a blank-line. Although, that won't be the case as the other application is guaranteed to write a valid entry, never a blank line. Note, that this is a very intermittent issue happening only in one particular environment which is a VM.

Comment: Actually, your point is valid. Inside the while-loop there indeed is a guard before it tries to determine hasReadOneLine. There were quite a few proprietary commented out debug statements in the code and I deleted them before posting here. Looks like I have deleted one additional line before that check: which is: if(!result.empty()) hasReadOneLine = (result[result.length()-1] == '\n');

Answer (score 0):

If your maximum line size is less than `MAX_BUF_SIZE`, then you may want to consider an alternative solution that would greatly simplify your implementation. In short, use `fread` instead of `fgets`:

```
void ReadLine(FILE* fp, std::string& result, bool& isEof)
{
    static char dataRead[MAX_BUF_SIZE] = {0};
    static int  dataindex = 0;
    int datalength = fread(dataRead,MAX_BUF_SIZE-dataindex,1,fp);
    for (int i=0; dataRead[i]!='\n'; i++)
        result += dataRead[i];
    dataindex = result.length()+1;
    memmove(dataRead,dataRead+dataindex,datalength-dataindex);
    isEof = feof(fp);
}
```

**Notes:**

1. This implementation assumes that the last line (hence the file itself) ends with a new-line character.
2. You can use `dataRead`/`dataindex` as a cyclic buffer in order to avoid the `memmove` operation.

Comment: @chux, can you please review and verify?

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the response. I am first trying to understand the problem in the present implementation before trying to change it. FYI, this code has been running in busy environments for years without any problem. The environment where this issue occurred is a test environment and is a Virtual Machine. Do you think this could be weird VM disk cache issue? The problem here is that the fgets(), which is a C-runtime function doesn't seem to move the file-pointer correctly to the end after reading. It can be a memory corruption in some other part of the application. I am unsure.

Comment: Hi. 1. I don't think it could have anything to do with the VM. 2. If the problem is in some other part of the application, then obviously you won't be able to get help in this context. 3. Is it possible that your code assumes that the last line in the input file ends with a new-line character (`\n`), even though it is not necessarily the case with some specific input files? 4. I think that your code trying to extract the next line **directly** from the input file, is in general a bad approach. That's why I suggested that you read the data into memory first, and find the next line in it instead

Comment: I get your suggestion and it is a good one. TBH, I too thought about it. However, I don't know where the problem lies in the present implementation. Here's few information. 1 - The application that writes into the file guarantees that it will write a valid line, never a blank line. 2 - Only this function uses the file pointer to read from a file, outside of this the file is only opened or closed. 3 - Problem appears when the app that is writing is doing so in high frequency. My specific question to you is: why is fgets() not moving the file pointer ahead after reading from it?

Comment: One obvious concern is if the Application's memory is getting corrupted by some other part. I am looking into that using some tools to try and ensure that there is no out-of-bounds write happening anywhere.

Comment: My apprehension with using fread() is what if that too returns me bits of previously read bytes, just like what fgets() is doing?

Comment: Any chance that the Writer app and the Reader app are accessing the file concurrently (simultaneously at the same time)?

Comment: Yes, that can happen. Basically think of it as we have one application that generates transaction and writes them in a text file - called transaction file. One line = one complete transaction. A line size can vary from few hundred characters to millions of characters. The other application is the one which opens the same transaction file in read-only mode (and in "text" mode, which I think is a bad idea), reads one line at a time, does some processing using the line read, then goes back to read the next line. The ReadLine() guarantees that this app never reads a partially written line.

Comment: Although it is not doing so because of an unexpected file read by fgets(). Also, each line is one complete XML document, that's how the application determines if the line read is valid or not.